# How I find out if the folder is the link to the same folder?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

In `VirtualBox -> Settings -> Storage -> Windows 7.vdi`

I have location: `/root/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/`.

But in `/home/xfce/` absolutely the same folder with same files.

I think the folder in `/home/xfce` is the link to the folder in `/root`.

Can I find out it with terminal without matching the size of folder?

Comment: `ls -l` will show long listed format and should show links

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` will show links.  Try to run `ls -l /root/VirtualBox VMs` and/or `ls -l /home/xfce`.

A link looks something like this:

```
$ ls -l /bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Dec 13  2016 /bin -> usr/bin
```

Here we can see `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`.  Another way is with the `readlink` tool:

```
$ readlink -f /bin
/usr/bin
```

The `-f` option shows the full path to the link.

Comment: So, in `/home/xfce/` aren't links. But `/home/xfce/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/` has 116K and `/root/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/` has 7.2G. Why I have the same folder in `/home/xfce` ?

Comment: @J.Doe: Sorry I'm not sure why your system is built the way it is.  I don't know why it contains a `Windows 7` directory at all.

Comment: I thought, that in `/root` is the main folder from VirtualBox and in `/home` is some symlinks, but if the command `ls -l` shows, that I am wrong, I am so confused now.

Comment: `/root` is the home directory for the root user.  `/home` is where the home directories for other users typically reside.  `/home/xfce` is the home directory of the `xfce` user.

Comment: I didn't want to write all the way to the file. The main folder from Windows 7 in VirtualBox is in `/root`. I think, that VirtualBox did the easy way to `Windows 7.vdi` like symlink in `/home/xfce`, but it's probably wrong.